# VBA Week Number from System Date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I was hoping you'd be able to help me out with a bit of code which calculates the Week Number based from the system date.
I have a TextBox `WeekNum`, which I want to show the Week Number for when `CommandButton1_Click` is activated.

I have found articles on how to calculate the Week Number from a given date, but I do not know enough VBA to change this to the system date.

Any help you can offer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA

```
Debug.Print Format(Now, "ww")
```

FORMULA

```
=1+INT((TODAY()-(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))))/7)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'll try to remember that one ;)